# How To Make a Method Using Swing, Sleep Using a Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, sleep

I've recently made a small puzzle game that deals with clicking certain areas. I also made a solver which activates the necessary areas to win. The problem that I am facing is that I would like to pause each time it activates an area to create a sort of "solving animation". My problem is represented here

```
package experiment; 
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ExperimentHere extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JButton changeLabelButton;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JLabel labelToChange;

public ExperimentHere() {
    changeLabelButton = new JButton("Set the label");
    changeLabelButton.addActionListener(this);

    mainPanel = new JPanel();

    labelToChange = new JLabel();
    labelToChange.setText("This needs to be changed");


    mainPanel.add(labelToChange);
    mainPanel.add(changeLabelButton);
    this.add(mainPanel);

    setTitle("Timer Program");
    setContentPane(mainPanel);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    pack();

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(changeLabelButton)){
        changeLabel();
    }
}

public void changeLabel(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        labelToChange.setText(""+i);
        // Pause for 200ms here

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ExperimentHere test = new ExperimentHere();
    test.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

I have tried using Timers, but I'm not sure how to format it properly so that it only pauses each time the loop inside of changeLabel() is incremented, because the second paramter in Timer() asks for an ActionListener.
I've also tried using Thread.sleep() but it just freezes my program and then instantly solves it.

Ideally the changeLabel method would increment by 1, set the label to the new String, wait for 200ms, and then increment again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried using Timers, but I'm not sure how to format it properly so that it only pauses each time the loop inside of changeLabel() is incremented

When you use a `Timer` you don't use a loop. The point of a `Timer` is that you start the Timer and it keeps executing until you stop the `Timer`.

You also don't make methods, you make an `Action` to invoke whenever the `Timer` fires.

So you need an instance variable in your class that keeps track of the number of times the Timer has fired (lets call it "timerCounter"). Then you need to create an `Action` to invoke every time the `Timer` is fired.

So you create a couple of instance variables:

```
int timerCounter = 0;
Action action;
```

Then in the constructor of your class you create an Action something like:

```
action = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        labelToChange.setText("" + timerCounter);
        timerCounter++;

        if (timerCounter > 5)
        {
            Timer timer = (Timer)e.getSource();
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

So now in the `ActionListener`of your button you can do something like:

```
timerCounter = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer(200, action);
timer.start();
```

Comment: Oh I see, I was misunderstanding the use of timers. Makes a lot more sense when it's used that like that. Thanks!

Comment: @Kazutadashi, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.